# Wordpress / Theme my login - custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, plugins, structure

I am using 'Theme my Login' in my wordpress-project.

Now i want to change the 'profile-form.php'-template.

What i did?

I copied the file

```
'wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/templates/profile-form.php'
```

into

```
'wp-content/themes/my-theme/profile-form.php'
```

Than I edited some lines and it worked.

But i have would like to have a nicer structure in my theme, like:

```
 'wp-content/themes/my-theme/theme-my-login/templates/profile-form.php'
```

But it does NOT work with this structure. Anybody could tell my why or how to fix this problem?

Greetings and Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried to fix this for your own? Please describe which steps you've done and where you got stuck. "does not work" does not qualify as a programming question here on Stackoverflow. Also asking for the tutorial or the documentation for what you would love to do is also considered off-topic. - I give you some documentation anyway in this comment: This is explained here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: I edited path in wordpress-backend, tried some settings in functions.php but there was no effect. So i just asked if anybody could help me running the custom-template with this structure. So?

Comment: Which path did you edit in wordpress-backend (and how is that related to theme files?). Which were the settings you just commented about? What were their previous values, which values did you choose and why? What could you found out why the settings had no effect?

Comment: omg, it just worked with this structure: 'wp-content/themes/my-theme/theme-my-login/profile-form.php', you knew about this?

Comment: it most likely depends on how you include the template file, the filenames are normally relative to the current theme directory. depending on which function you use to load the template (part), more information is available in codex for that function.